# Chaining RESTful endpoint invocations in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have seen countless posts on SO that seem to dance around what I'm trying to accomplish, but none of them hit the mark. So.... here's another post about chaining RESTful endpoint invocations in Angular. Here's my simplified example:

Given a data model of Student, Course, & Enrollment:

```
interface Student {
  id: number;
  studentName: string;
}

interface Course { 
  id: number;
  courseName: string;
}

interface Enrollment {
  studentId: number;
  courseId: number;
}
```

...and given the following method in my Angular service:

```
getEnrollmentsForStudent(studentId: number): Observable<Enrollment[]> {
   return this.http.get<Enrollment[]>('http://url/enrollment?id='+studentId);
}
```

I need to write a 2nd method with the following signature:

```
getCoursesForStudent(studentId: number): Observable<Course[]> {
   ...
}
```

that uses the Enrollment array from the getEnrollmentsForStudent method to get all the relevant Course objects (here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chain-observables?file=src/app/registration.service.ts)). I'm sure there is some magic combo of RxJS operators to do this, but I've struck out trying to figure it out.

Edit: here's a minimal reproducible example of my Angular service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';


interface Student {
  id: number;
  studentName: string;
}

interface Course { 
  id: number;
  courseName: string;
}

interface Enrollment {
  studentId: number;
  courseId: number;
}


@Injectable()
export class RegistrationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEnrollmentsForStudent(studentId: number): Observable<Enrollment[]> {
    return this.http.get<Enrollment[]>('http://url/enrollment?id=studentId');
  }

  getCoursesForStudent(studentId: number): Observable<Course[]> {
    // 1. get Enrollments for student using getEnrollemtnsForStudent
    // 2. for each enrollment, get the course
    // 3. return array of Course objects
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your stack blitz link is giving a 404

Comment: I'd guess this is a `pipe` to `mergeMap`ping a `forkJoin`, but it would be helpful to show a bit more of your research and put a [mre] in the question.

Comment: Sorry @cjd82187 - link fixed!

Comment: @jonrsharpe added!

Comment: I meant more of a plausible attempt to apply what you'd learned, `return null` isn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use switchMap.  I don't know what your endpoint for getting the Courses looks like, so I took a guess of sending an array of IDs as a query string...

You're `getCoursesForStudent` calls the `getEnrollmentsForStudent` method, and pipe's its array of enrollments via the `switchMap` and makes the 2nd API call returning an Observable of the 2nd call.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chain-observables-ck6oyt?file=src/app/registration.service.ts

```js
getCoursesForStudent(studentId: number): Observable<Course[]> {
    // 1. get Enrollments for student using getEnrollemtnsForStudent
    // 2. for each enrollment, get the course
    // 3. return array of Course objects
    return this.getEnrollmentsForStudent(studentId).pipe(switchMap(enrollments => {
      const enrollmentIds = enrollments.map(e => e.courseId);
      // Not sure what your API expects to get an array of IDs, just guessing here...
      return this.http.get<Course[]>(`http://url/courses?ids_in=${enrollmentIds}`);
    }));
  }
```

Comment: This does the trick. Now I just need to learn the guts of what "pipe" and "switchMap" are really doing for me. Thank you!